# PHP Losing session

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a page which allows me to put a product in my shopping cart but when i refresh the page it loses my product.

Here is the page product page simplified (without all the html):

```
<?php 

session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['panier']);

?>
<input type="button" value="Ajouter au panier" name="addtocart" class="addtocart" id="addtocart_id">
<script>
        function ajoutPanier(){
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var quantite = document.getElementById('qte_id').value;
            var taille = document.getElementById('choosetaille_id').value;
            var produit = document.getElementById('title_product').textContent;
            var prix = document.getElementById('price_product').textContent;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "panierajax.php?PHPSESSID=<?php echo $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']; ?>&quantite=" + quantite + "&taille=" + taille + "&produit=" + produit + "&prix=" + prix, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        var buttonPanier = document.querySelector('#addtocart_id');
        buttonPanier.addEventListener('click', ajoutPanier);
</script>
```

Here is the panierajax.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

$quantite   = $_GET['quantite'];
$produit    = $_GET['produit'];
$prix       = $_GET['prix'];
$taille     = $_GET['taille'];


if(!isset($_SESSION['panier'])){
    $_SESSION['panier'] = [];
    $_SESSION['panier']['quantite'] = [];
    $_SESSION['panier']['produit'] = [];
    $_SESSION['panier']['prix'] = [];
    $_SESSION['panier']['taille'] = [];
    
}
array_push($_SESSION['panier']['quantite'], $quantite);
array_push($_SESSION['panier']['produit'], $produit);
array_push($_SESSION['panier']['prix'], $prix);
array_push($_SESSION['panier']['taille'], $taille);

?>
```

The first time i add a product, when i refresh the product page i see my shopping cart with this product.
If i refresh it a second time my var_dump shows me NULL.

I looked in the php.ini file and my session_lifetime is equal to 0 so i don't know why i lose it when i refresh the page.

If anyone has any suggestions..

Comment: FYI there should be absolutely no need to pass the session ID manually in the AJAX request.

Comment: Anyway there's absolutely nothing in the code you've provided which would allow us to analyse why you might be seeing a result like this. We can't even see the code where you're displaying the products, or anything else about how you're managing the session. We'll need more info - see [How to Create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 for extra guidance.

Comment: If your POST updated the db after each submit in the cart via a session in the mysql db, for example, then GET that info from the db session, I would guess it'd work. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver